# SharedPreferences not saving properly - android

Tags: java, android, sharedpreferences

I'm trying to use sharedpreferences to store an integer. Something is wrong though, so the integer won't get saved. Whenever I stop my app the integer won't show up, it isn't there and isn't getting saved. Here's my code that's located in my `onCreate()` method:

```java
private int point;

//...

SharedPreferences sp = getSharedPreferences("prefs_file",MODE_PRIVATE);
SharedPreferences.Editor editor = sp.edit();
editor.putInt("your_int_key", point);
editor.apply();

SharedPreferences sp1 = getSharedPreferences("prefs_file",MODE_PRIVATE);
int highScoreSaved = sp1.getInt("your_int_key", 0);
```

Comment: What do you mean by "whenever I stop my app the integer won't show up" ?

Comment: Where are you putting this code inside your app(onCreate, onResume, etc.)? Can you edit your post to include this code?

Comment: It's in my onCreate(). Sorry for not giving that information

Comment: You may want to consider moving your `putInt` code into onPause, onStop, or onDestroy. I'm guessing you'll want to use onDestroy but I'm not sure how your app works. I'm still not understanding what you mean by "whenever you stop the app" though.

Comment: Are you writing any value in your `point` variable? Are you using the value you get from `SharedPreferences`? Show us the whole code.

Comment: Basically by "whenever you stop the app" I mean like when I turn my device off or just force it to shutdown. I don't know how a more formal way to say it. And I don't use point anywhere else except for what I've posted and later where I use the variable to a textview, which can't possible be relevant.

Comment: So you're storing `point` in shared preferences before you assign it a value?

 Look, all we can do is guess what might be wrong if we can't get an idea of how your code works. If all this is in your onCreate, it already doesn't make sense that you would store in shared preferences and then retrieve from it in the same place.

Answer (score -2):

Try sp1.commit().

Have a look at the developer guide:

https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/data-storage.html#pref

Comment: I guess you mean editor.commit(); Sorry, that doesn't work. :(